# Parsing a string to "year-month-day" format in C#

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime

Im using a webservice that needs a datetime in the following format "2010-12-24"

I have the string to parse in the same "way" but as said, its a String.

```
string myDate = "2010-12-24";
```

How can i parse it so that it gets the same format?

Have tried using : `DateTime.Parse(mystring);`

but this gives me a colon separated format.

Comment: In which format is the string you need to convert *from*?

Comment: The same format: "2010-10-24"

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx), providing a [custom format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx):

```
DateTime.ParseExact(mystring, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

This will throw an exception if the input string cannot be parsed - you may want to use [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBUQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx&ei=z8XGTLm2MOqS4gbYn7D-Dw&usg=AFQjCNFQGjkGdGxsoLV-gH7CNHsxXlPkVQ) which will return true if successful.

Comment: What are the reasons it cant be parsed?

Comment: @matskn - if the string passed in is not a date `myString = "abcdsd"`.

Comment: return DateTime.TryParseExact(text,format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,DateTimeStyles.None, out date);

Comment: @phil123456 - that will return a boolean (the return type of `TryParseExact`), somehow, I don't think that's the wanted return value...

Answer (score 5):

You can use

```
ToString( formatString )
```

Eg:- `dateTimeObj.ToString( "yyyy-MM-dd" );`
Where dateTimeObj is your DateTime object

Comment: You are showing the overload that uses a `FormatProvider` and suggesting to use the one that uses a `string`. These are two _different_ overloads.

Comment: @Oded - Sorry, my mistake. I did not mean FormatProvider object there. I just meant it to be format string.

Answer (score 4):

`DateTime time = DateTime.Now;

string format = "yyyy-M-d";

Console.WriteLine(time.ToString(format));`

Comment: alternatively "yyyy-MM-dd" if your string can contain trailing zeros.

Answer (score 2):

The most efficient way is to use `DateTime.TryParseExact()`:

```
DateTime result;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(input, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out result))
{
    // use result
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```